# What happens before JSF Restore View

Tags: jsf, web-applications, jsf-2, websphere

I have a JSF 1.2 Application with welcome file as 
login.jsp deployed in WAS (IBM).
What happens when a user enter login.jsp in browser's address bar till it reaches JSF's 'Restore View' life cycle event for login.jsp ?

Comment: Am i asking the wrong question ?

Comment: Servlet filters are fired, servlet service method is invoked, FacesContex is created... You can start with service method of FacesServlet (http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/myfaces/core/branches/1.2.x/api/src/main/java/javax/faces/webapp/FacesServlet.java) and see for yourself.